# What are all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n+13}{n-7}\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n+13}{n-7}\in\mathbb{N}$.

$\frac{n+13}{n-7}=1+\frac{20}{n-7}$ so we have $20\ge n-7>0$ that mean $27\ge n>7$ so

$n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{n+13}{n-7}\in\mathbb{N}$ are the ones that $\in [27,0)$ such that $n-7|20$

is that true?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly right.

Comment: True about $n-7\mathrel|20$, but that includes when $n-7=20$ instead of the absolute inequality $20>n-7$ you wrote.

Comment: Yes. Now you are probably expected to list them. The stuff about $27$ is not really necessary, since the list in any case is short.